# How can I remote debug a PWA that has been "added to homescreen" on Android?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, progressive-web-apps

I have installed a PWA on my Android device and I want to remotely debug it in Chrome on my desktop.  When I connect to my device in Chrome dev tools, all I see are the tabs open in Chrome on my Android device.  I do not see the instance of the PWA that has been installed - "added to homescreen"  Is there any way to debug the installed instance?

Comment: What is failing on the device that you cannot debug in Chrome?

Comment: Nothing is failing, the installed PWA is just not visible. If I load up the PWA in Chrome (on the Android device) then I can remotely debug it.  I simply can't debug the version installed via "add to homescreen".

Answer (score 5):

1. You have to open your developer tools using  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
2. Then go to **More Tools** -> **Remote Devices**
   [image: Inspect_element]
3. In Remote devices, you can see your available online device and click on that(either online device can be emulator or it can be attached mobile device), also you can **Add Rule** if you want to run in localhost from mobile device.
   [image: Remote devices]
4. Click on **Inspect** button, available in right side
   [image: Inspect]
5. Now you can see virtual device is created and you can see all logs that comes from device will display in **Console tab**
   [image: console]

Comment: The device is visible, but as said in the question, the device"s screen is not visible and you can't see source code. And in some cases, when you build data base on the device, they stay invisible under chrome.

Comment: I have no remote devices option

Comment: @HadiFarnoud You have to downgrde your Google chrome version to 67. In latest google chrome you can not find remote device option

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Turns out that PWAs that were open before you connected remote debugger will not show up. Simply close the app and start it after connecting the debugger.